# How would I formulate an "ip route" command in order for two non-adjacent routers to communicate?

Tags: cisco, routing, router, subnet, packet-tracer

I am doing static routing to connect computers over three routers.

Here is my scenario:
[image: network]

Each of the hosts are in `/21` subnets. Each of the routers are assigned IP addresses over a `/30` subnet. When I go in each of the routers' CLIs, I can ping a host on the `VanNuys` to a host on `Seattle` and I can ping a host on `Seattle` to a host on `OK City`.

My trouble now is figuring out how a host on `Van Nuys` can successfully ping one on `OK City`. Could such a thing be possible using this configuration or would I have to add an additional serial cable that goes directly from `OK City` to `Van Nuys`? If so, what would that look like?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I must've forgotten about that.. thanks!

Comment: That was fast! I periodically search through old questions with answers to see if any can be closed. I went through several thousand last year, and we got hundreds closed. Fortunately, we are small enough that works, but I couldn't imagine trying to do it on [so].

Comment: Yeah, I bet! Thankfully I got the notification from my phone so that was enough to remind me. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add routes to the networks on the other side of the other router. You did that already for some of your routes, but you need to do it for all of the routes.

Static routes don't scale. You should really use a dynamic routing protocol in common with your routers.

---

You obviously created static routes on your routers in order for a host on the Van Nuys network to be able to ping a host on the Seattle network. Something like:

```
ip route <destination network address> <destination network mask> <next hop router>
```

You did this on the Van Nuys router, pointing to the Seattle router, and vice versa. You need to do the same thing for any other networks on the other side of the Seattle router, including the link from the Seattle router to the OK City router, and the network on the other side of the OK City router. From Van Nuys, those networks are on the other side of the Seattle router, which is the next hop router for the networks attached to the Seattle router. You will also need to do the same thing on the OK City router for the networks on the other side of the Seattle router from the perspective of the OK City router.